# match the value of two columns of two different worksheets in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, worksheet

here is my code below  i was trying to write a program to match values two columns of two different worksheets using vba by using this code

---

```
Sub Compare2Worksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)

Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long

Set report = Workbooks.Add
With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With
With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With
maxrow = ws1row
maxcol = ws1col

If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

difference = 0

For col = 1 To maxcol
    For Row = 1 To maxrow
        colval1 = ""
        colval2 = ""
        colval1 = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula
        colval2 = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula

        If colval <> colval2 Then
            difference = difference + 1
            Cells(Row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
            Cells(Row, col).Interior.Color = 255
            Cells(Row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
            Cells(Row, col).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next Row
Next col

Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
report.Saved = True

If difference = 0 Then
    report.Close False
End If
Set report = Nothing

MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets cells contain different data", vbInformation, "Comparing two worksheet "

End Sub
```

---

code for the button

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Compare2Worksheets Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")     

End Sub
```

---

I am getting an error here

```
MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets cells contain different data", vbInformation, "Comparing two worksheet "
```

as some type mismatch error while i was trying to click on the button for running the program kindly help me in solving the error...

Comment: `colval1 = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula
        colval1 = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula` shouldn't it be 
       `colval1 = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula
        colval2 = ws2.Cells(Row, col).Formula`

Comment: have done that program is running but it is unable to perform comparison and to provide desired results

Comment: still the type mismatch error is coming

Comment: what about the corrections mentioned below?

Comment: @saurabh255 see my answer and code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MsgBox` contains too many `String` parameters. Try changing it to the code below:

```
MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets cells contain different data"
```

Besides that, your line:

```
If colval <> colval2 Then
```

should be:

```
If colval1 <> colval2 Then
```

Also, try not to use `Row` as a variable, as it's a saved Excel "word", usr `iRow` instead (or anything else).

---

Try the code below (explanations inside the code's comments):

```
Dim wsResult As Worksheet

Set report = Workbooks.Add
Set wsResult = report.Worksheets(1) ' <-- set the worksheet object

With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count '<-- had an error here (was `ws2col`)
End With
With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With

' Use Max function 
maxrow = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1row, ws2row)
maxcol = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1col, ws2col)

'maxrow = ws1row
'maxcol = ws1col    
'If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
'If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

difference = 0

For col = 1 To maxcol
    For iRow = 1 To maxrow
        colval1 = ""
        colval2 = ""
        colval1 = ws1.Cells(iRow, col).Formula
        colval2 = ws2.Cells(iRow, col).Formula ' <-- you had an error here, you used `colval1 = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula`

        If colval1 <> colval2 Then '<-- you had an error here (used `If colval <> colval2`)
            difference = difference + 1
            ' don't rely on ActiveSheet, use the wsResult worksheet object
            wsResult.Cells(iRow, col).Formula = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
            wsResult.Cells(iRow, col).Interior.Color = 255
            wsResult.Cells(iRow, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
            wsResult.Cells(iRow, col).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next iRow
Next col

wsResult.Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
report.Saved = True

If difference = 0 Then
    report.Close False
End If
Set report = Nothing

MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets cells contain different data"
```

Answer (score 1):

variable `maxcolumn` not initialized(see comment in the code below)

```
With ws1.UsedRange
        ws1row = .Rows.Count
        ws2col = .Columns.Count //it should be: ws1col
    End With
    With ws2.UsedRange
        ws2row = .Rows.Count
        ws2col = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxrow = ws1row
    maxcol = ws1col
```